# ODE with complex char roots gives strange solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, roots

$y''-4y'+5y=0$ has char roots - $\{e^{(2+i)x},e^{(2-i)x}\}.$

So its solutions is $e^{2x}\cos(x), e^{2x}\sin(x).$

But when i plug, e.g., first of them into original eq. i get:

$-4 e^{2x} cos(x) + 8 e^{2x} sin(x) + 5 e^{2x} cos(x)$ must be equal to zero.

$e^{2x} (cos(x) + 8 sin(x))$ and this is definitely not zero. Why?

Comment: The arithmetic must have gone awry, perhaps there was a mistake in computing the derivative, or a minus sign error later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - you should be carrying a factor $e^{2x}$, which gives a factor $2$ each time you differentiate

Second - you should show the outcome of your differentiations - as you have stated your result, it is difficult to see how you reached the result you did.

It came out for me.

Comment: Example taken from Wikipedia article `Linear differential equation`. I just have the same problem with my equation but i took  eq from Wiki to be sure.

Comment: @yola I get $y=e^{2x}\cos x$; $y'=2e^{2x}\cos x-e^{2x}\sin x$; $y''=3e^{2x}\cos x-4e^{2x}\sin x$ - what do you get.

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong

Comment: @Yola - I was using the product rule for differentiation ...

Answer (score 1):

General solution is $$y=Ae^{2x}\cos x+Be^{2x} \sin x$$
The derivatives are
$$y'=(2A+B)e^{2x}\cos x+(2B-A)e^{2x} \sin x
\\ y''=(3A+4B)e^{2x}\cos x+(3B-4A)e^{2x} \sin x$$
Then you have to verify